# Как разделить панель и JInternalFrame, которые лежат на одном уровне?

Tags: java, swing

Имеется приложение для тестирования.
У меня есть панелька регистрации `jInternalFrame` и сама панель тестирования, они лежат на одном уровне и залезают друг на друга.
Так вот:

Как поставить `JInternalFrame` со всеми его компонентами выше второй панельки?

[image: окно NetBeans]
[image: то что происходит]

Comment: Простите, что не по теме, но кто заставил Вас писать на swing'е?
Есть JavaFX, есть Scene Builder (http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/), они несколько проще в обращении, чем swing, весьма гибки в настройке и разнообразны. В JavaFX Вы просто поместите нужные элементы в контейнер (Group, HBox, VBox или нечто подобное) и они из него никуда не будут торчать. При этом Вы можете влиять на отображение элементов сцены с помощью CSS - удобно!

По вопросу - не могли бы Вы пронумеровать на картинке панельки - какую панельку Вы назвали первой, какую второй? Спасибо. И ещё раз простите за офтоп.

Answer (score 2):

Уже решил свою проблему. Помог JDesktopPane и CardLayout и в него все панели добавил